# Auto resize Spark NavigatorContent

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I have next hierarchy:

```
<s:TabBar dataProvider="{stack}" />
<mx:ViewStack id="stack" width="100%">
    <s:NavigatorContent width="100%" label="123" backgroundColor="#c02c31" >
        <s:BorderContainer minHeight="200">
            <s:List id="testList" width="100%" contentBackgroundColor="#f00fff" contentBackgroundAlpha="0"/>
        </s:BorderContainer>
    </s:NavigatorContent>
</mx:ViewStack>
```

And I want achieve next: when `testList.dataProvider` have changed, List changes its size, and NavigatorContent also changes its size. But now NavigatorContent doesn't change it size depends on its children. What I am doing wrong?

I wrote code to test it:

```
    private var _testDP1:Array = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg"];
    private var _testDP2:Array = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg"];
    private var _someFlag:Boolean = false;

    private function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if (!_someFlag)
        {
            testList.dataProvider = new ArrayList(_testDP1);
            _someFlag = true;
        } else
        {
            testList.dataProvider = new ArrayList(_testDP2);
            _someFlag = false;
        }

    }
```

And how it looks now.
At start: http://gyazo.com/65755dbd66346a49455344a767098b27

With _testDP1: http://gyazo.com/007a76d03cc8c9c88c75439446e01102

With _testDP2: http://gyazo.com/7dfccf00b7c39f6eb1cdac96298893d1

UPD:

I check with another parent (but with same skin): `SkinnableContainer`. And it works properly. So something wrong with NavigatorContent or ViewStack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution myself. There is a magic property `resizeToContent` that solve my problem!